# Core Data: storing ordered values in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: core-data

I'm building a workout app that has an entity called Workout and another one called Exercise.
A workout can contain multiple exercises (thus a one-to-many relationship). I want to show the users of my app the exercises contained in a workout but in an ordered way (it's not the same to start with strength exercises as with the cardio ones).

Apparently, when establishing this kind of relationship in Core Data, I need to use an `NSSet`, because if I try to use for example an `Array` where its elements are ordered, I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "consistsOf"; desired type = NSSet; given type = __NSArray0; value = (
).'
```

I have tried to check the "ordered" checkmark in my model, but then I get an error saying "Workout.consistsOf must not be ordered".
I have also tried to use an `NSDictionary` whose keys would be the position and the values would be the exercises themselves, but I'm getting the same error as above.

How can I show the users the exercises that a workout consists of in an ordered way?

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S.: Here's a screenshot of the properties of my model.

[image: model properties]
[image: error]

Comment: I think checking "ordered" makes Core Data use NSOrderedSet

Comment: indeed it does, and after converting my property to be an `NSORderedSet`, I'm still getting: `Workout.consistsOf must not be ordered [8]`. I have also realized that the title of the error says `CloudKit integration`

Comment: Ok, then it is another situation. I am no expert on CloudKit since I have just started using it but it certainly effects (adds more constraints) what you can do with Core Data. Another option is of course to add your own order property to Exercise.

Comment: Afraid it's one of those little wrinkles that CloudKit doesn't support the (NS)OrderedSet mapping - at least that's what I found when I ran into the same problem last year :-/.  Most folks appear to be working around the limitation by adding an additional priority attribute to the entity that needs sorting (rather than anything more complicated like a linked list or similar).

Comment: Here's a bit more confirming previous comment and a suggestion for an alternate approaches https://www.appsdissected.com/order-core-data-entities-maximum-speed/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ordered relationships use `NSOrderedSet`, but CloudKit doesn't support ordered sets, so you can't use an ordered relationship and CloudKit in the same data model.

To keep an order, you need to have some property on `Exercise` that would indicate the order. This could be as simple as an integer property called something like `index`. You'd sort the result based on the index value. If there's something else that also indicates order-- like a date, maybe?-- use that instead of adding a new property.

Comment: thanks for the info! I ended up creating an intermediate table that adds an order of an exercise in a workout

Comment: @noloman Did you handle the case where 2 (offline) devices create exercises that have the same `index` value?